# YCbCr at LipMap detection

Tags: java

I'm confused with converting the `RGB` values to `YCbCr` color scheme. I used this equation:

```
int R, G, b;

double Y = 0.229 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.144 * B;
double Cb = -0.168 * R - 0.3313 * G + 0.5 * B + 128;
double Cr = 0.5 * R - 0.4187 * G - 0.0813 * B + 128;
```

The expected output of YCbCr is normalized between 0-255, I'm confused because one of my source says it is normalized within the range of 0-1. 
And it is going well, But I am having problem when getting the LipMap to isolate/detect the lips of the face, I implemented this:

```
double LipMap = Cr*Cr*(Cr*Cr-n*(Cr/Cb))*(Cr*Cr-n*(Cr/Cb));
```

n returns 0-255, the equation for n is: n=0.95*(summation(Cr*Cr)/summation(Cr/Cb))
but another sources says: n = 0.95*(((1/k)*summation(Cr*Cr))/((1/k)*summation(Cr/Cb)))
where k is equal to the number of pixels in the face image.

It say's from my sources that it will return a result of `0-255`, but in my program it always returns large numbers always, not even giving me `0-255`.

So can anyone help me implement this and solve my problem?

Comment: Please help me: what is a LipMap? Do you mean a lip map, as in detect lips in a face?

Comment: What values do you get for `Y`, `Cb` and `Cr`? Are they in the range 0-255? And what is the value of `n`?

Comment: I have updated the question, sorry I think my question is not that complete of imformation...
I hope that you could share your knowledge to me Sir

Comment: Could you link those sources? I suspect that your `Cr` and `Cb` calculations are wrong. If you do those calculations for a single red pixel yourself (on paper) you'll see that for values in range 0-255 the `LipMap` value gets way too high unless there's some additional normalization. If you do it for values in the range 0-1 (i.e. `Cb = 0.332` and `Cr = 1.0` for `R=1,G=0,B=0`) I get `LipMap ~ 0.997`, which seems reasonable to me.

Comment: These are my sources: http://www.feec.vutbr.cz/EEICT/2004/sbornik/03-Doktorske_projekty/08-Grafika_a_multimedia/02-galilleo.pdf  and http://profdoc.um.ac.ir/articles/a/1010171.pdf

Comment: Yeah, that's what makes me confused, because I'm expecting 0-255 output on that LipMap equation. I have also done using RGB with 0-1 value's, but still I got large output, but maybe I got a wrong implementation...MAYBE.... You've enlightened my mind and I thank you for that, I hope you can give me your side after you've read my sources.... Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

From the sources you linked in your comments, it looks like either the equations or the descriptions in the first source are wrong:

If you use RGB values in the Range [0,255] and the given conversion (your `Cb` conversion differs from that btw.) you should get `Cr` and `Cb` values in the same range.

Now if you calculate *n = 0.95 * (ΣC<sub>r</sub><sup>2</sup>/Σ(C<sub>r</sub>/C<sub>b</sub>))* you'll notice that the values for C<sub>r</sub><sup>2</sup> range from [0,65025] whereas C<sub>r</sub>/C<sub>b</sub> is in the range [0,255] (assuming C<sub>b</sub>=0 is not possible and thus the highest value would be 255/1 = 255).

If you further assume an image with quite high red and low blue components, you'll get way higher values for *n* than what is stated in that paper:

> Constant η fits final value in range 0..255

The second paper states this, which makes much more sense IMHO (although I don't know whether they normalize C<sub>r</sub> and C<sub>b</sub> to range [0,1] before the calculation or if they normalize the result which might result in a higher difference between C<sub>r</sub><sup>2</sup> and C<sub>r</sub>/C<sub>b</sub>):

> Where (Cr) 2,(Cr/Cb) all are normalized to the
>   range [0 1].

Note that in order to normalize C<sub>r</sub> and C<sub>b</sub> to range [0,1] you'd either need to divide the result of your equations by 255 or simply use RGB in range [0,1] and add 0.5 instead of 128:

```
//assumes RGB are in range [0,1]
double Cb = -0.168 * R - 0.3313 * G + 0.5 * B + 0.5;
double Cr = 0.5 * R - 0.4187 * G - 0.0813 * B + 0.5;
```

Comment: So according to your answer, I should do it like this:

Comment: So according to your answer, I should do it like this:                                                                     double red = R/255; double green = G/255; double blue = B/255;                                                                    double Cb = -0.168 * red - 0.3313 * green + 0.5 * blue +0.5;                                                                     double Cr = 0.5 * red - 0.4187 * green - 0.0813 * blue + 0.5;                                                                  Then I implement the LipMap equation, am I right?

Comment: @jpeter723 Yes that seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I'm really having a hard time trying to figure out how this equation works...